# Which .tpl file should I use to theme the quiz module's detail page?

Tags: 7, theming, quiz

I am using the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module for a requirement.

I want to theme the quiz *detail page*, *multiple choice questions page* and the *Jquery timer* which I am using with that page.

Which `.tpl` files should I edit for this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer surely will be here it describes how to create a .tpl files for ehat you want [D7 theme suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)